# How to connect Bloomberg's xbbp api to "Bloomberg Anywhere"

Tags: programming, time-series, bloomberg, tick-data

Due to COVID's remote work situation I found myself unable to access my physical terminal so I've had to use *bloomberg anywhere (bba)*, the issue I'm having is that when I try to use python's xbbg on my mac to extract intraday tick data i get a `"ConnectionError: Cannot connect to Bloomberg"`

Does anyone know a way to connect python/xbbg to bba?

Alternatively could I save that level of detailed data directly from the terminal? If I could then I'd just email it to myself, but I don't know if that's possible

Thanks!

Comment: If you're able to log in to the terminal, you should ask Bloomberg support F1 F1

Comment: William Dolittle at your service. A.K.A., Will Do. I'll give it a shot and report back hopefully with news that can help more people in my situation!

Comment: If you don't need alot of data and only want to do casual analysis, one solution would be to export to excel in your bloomberg anywhere (citrix) session, copy the data to clipboard and use the pandas read_clipboard() method.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: @pruefsumme no luck on that, seems like you need to be local.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that is really best ask on the help desk `F1 F1`.

You can only access BBG on a MAC via the Citrix plug-in and https://bba.bloomberg.net.

This will not establish a connection with your mac though. Hence, your local Python will not work. Only the excel API can be used like that.

Windows users can download the actual [software](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/software-updates/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwppSEBhCGARIsANIs4p6iUZFy_iRZgQaRjUzJD23HcRh1oLs52GhtCqkucpQBSs05XFKQYokaArH1EALw_wcB). In this case you could use it normally.

Comment: Can you just install Windows via a virtual machine, then install it and use the python commands there?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://assets.bbhub.io/professional/sites/10/workstation_requirements_70en.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwio-fqghdn9AhXd7rsIHSuACdQQFnoECBYQBg&usg=AOvVaw3s8MSMz3XGodFTyM8QgLQA